# Passing settings to slick carousel directive in angular not work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to integrate slick carousel in to my angular application on model. Slick already has a directive, so the only thing that I need to do in my html is this:

```
  <slick    settings="slickConfig" >
                            <div class="slider-for-item">

                                <img src="/Content/images/condo/condo-1.jpg">

                            </div >
                            <div class="slider-for-item">
                                <img src="/Content/images/condo/condo-2.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="slider-for-item">
                                <img src="/Content/images/condo/condo-3.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </slick>
```

Okay, so it works. But now if I want to pass some settings to add them as attributes on the  element
This also works, but I want to pass those settings from my angular app and not inside the html any suggestion of how doing this? Trying to pass the settings like this:

```
    cdkApp.controller('buildingDetailsPopupController',   ["$scope","$uibModalInstance",
    function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.slickConfig = {
         autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000
    };
}]);
```

call a modal window

```
   controller.buildingDetailsPopup = function () {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "/app/View/Partials/_buildingDetailsPopup.html",
        controller: 'buildingDetailsPopupController',
        size: 'lg'

    });
```